# iPhone - Fixed (tableHeaderView) with grouped UITableView while scrolling cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

I have a `UIView` with a grouped `UITableView` and I'd like the `UIView` to stay as a fixed `tableHeaderView`, rather than moving when scrolling the `UITableViewCell`'s. Therefore I'd like the cells to be behind the `UIView` when scrolling.

This is the code I'm currently using to add my `UIView` to my `UIViewController`:

Interface.h:

```
@interface MyAccountVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    HeaderView *myHeaderView; // Inherits from UIView
    UITableView *tv;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tv;
@property (nonatomic, retain) HeaderView myHeaderView;
```

Implementation.m (in viewDidLoad):

```
// Set up the table's header view based on our UIView 'HeaderView' outlet.
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:nil options:nil];

for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        self.myHeaderView = (HeaderView *)currentObject;
        break;
    }
}

CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.tv.bounds.size.width, self.myHeaderView.frame.size.height);
self.myHeaderView.frame = newFrame;

self.tv.tableHeaderView = self.myHeaderView;
```

Not sure if this is the best way of adding `myHeaderView` to the `UITableView`, but it seems to be working fine and I can simply add the above code to any `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` to re-use the header if need be.

At the moment the header moves with the cells as I scroll, but I'd like the header to be fixed just below the top `UINavigationBar` while the cells move freely and behind the header. Please let me know if this all makes sense or whether you need more code in order to determine what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just elaborating on Paramasivan's answer.

I don't create views with nib files, so I will describe the code assuming you create views programmatically.

What you need to do is, just place header view at the top, and place a sized tableview below top.

Example:

```
- (void) loadView {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    self.view = view;

    self.myHeaderView = ... // use your init function, with rect something like (0,0,320,50)
    [view addsubview:self.myHeaderView];

    self.tv = [[UITableView alloc] init... // with frame like (0,50,320,430)
    [view addSubview:self.tv];

    // release everything
}
```

This way, you have a UIView that's always at the top of the view, and won't scroll with tableview.

If you add myHeaderView to be the tableview headerView, it will always scroll with the tableview I think.

In your example, using nib, you can probably resize the frame in the "viewDidLoad" function so that UITableView starts at position (0, myHeaderView.frame.size.height).

EDIT* finally figured out how to use 4 spaces for code formatting :)

Comment: I've done this from the .xib as well. I placed a UIView near the top, then added a UITableView to fill the space below it. If you allow rotation, just be careful to set the autoresizingmasks the way you want them.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom `UIViewController` and implement the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols yourself.

Add the `UITableView` to your `UIViewController` then add your custom `UIView` on top of the `UITableView` simply by calling the `-addSubview:(UIView *)view` method. Set the UITableView content and scroll inset properties.

Example:

```
[tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(44.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, 44.0f)];
[[self view] addSubview:tableView];

UIView *viewAboveTableView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)];
[[self view] addSubview:viewAboveTableView];
```

You could also use a `UIImageView` below the `UIView` that is on top of the UITableView and has an image that starts out transparent and fades in to the color of the `UIView`. This would give the appearance that the cells are going behind the `UIView`.

This would be easier done in code than in Interface Builder. In my experience adding UIView objects on top of other views confuses Interface Builder especially if it is a UITableView. For some reason it also slows down Interface Builder considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the view just above UITableView instead of having it inside as headerview.

Comment: Yes, have an UIView just above UITableView. Programmatically saying [self.view addSubview:viewHeader]; [self.view addSubview tableViewList];

Comment: If I do this then the UIView covers the first couple of cells.

Comment: Then set the table's contentInset. ;)